# How to pass multiple value in laravel json file?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, api, parameter-passing

I am working having laravel api. I'm in trouble with passing iteration value through laravel json.Here the code...

```
 public function show($quizResultId)
{
    //QuizResult
    $quizResult=QuizResult::findOrFail($quizResultId);
    $quizSessionId=$quizResult->session_id;
    //QuizSessionAns
    $quizSessionAns=QuizSessionAnswer::where('session_id','=',$quizSessionId)->get();
    $quizSessionAns=$quizSessionAns->pluck('selected_choice_id');
    //QuizSession
    $quizSession=QuizSession::findOrFail($quizSessionId);
    //Question with Choices
    $quizId=$quizSession->quiz_id;
    $quiz=Quiz::with('questions.choices')->findOrFail($quizId);
    $questions=$quiz->questions;
    
    $questionLimit=$questions->count();

    for($i=0;$i<$questionLimit;$i++){
        $questionChoice=$questions[$i];
        $chosenAns=$quizSessionAns[$i];

    return response()->json([
        'quiz_session'=>$quizSession,
        'question_with_choice'=>$questionChoice,
        'candidate_chosen_ans'=>$chosenAns
    ]);
    }
}
```

Here the loop doesn't work.So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement is in loop so on first iteration it will simply break the loop and return the result. Instead you should do something like this:

```
$questionChoice = [];
$chosenAns = [];

for($i=0;$i<$questionLimit;$i++){
    $questionChoice[]=$questions[$i];
    $chosenAns[]=$quizSessionAns[$i];
}

return response()->json([
            'quiz_session'=>$quizSession,
            'question_with_choice'=>$questionChoice,
            'candidate_chosen_ans'=>$chosenAns
        ]);
```